# Global searchin multisite but only with one subsite

Tags: multisite, search

I have a multisite set up with currently 2 subsites.
Is it possible to have a search box that searches the main site and just one subsite?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-global-search/ it uses MySQL views to achieve a global search. Maybe you can use it, or adapt it to your needs?